# How many times do you have to 'tap' a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

When a Pokemon appears in the wild, you have to tap it to enter the 'catching' stage.

I've noticed sometimes I have to tap *quite a lot* to enter that stage; other times I only have to tap once. Sometimes I tap furiously and nothing happens - the wild Pokemon eventually disappears.

Is there a correlation between number of taps required and the experience points of the Pokemon? Or is one tap enough and the failed ones are just server timeouts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should only have to tap a pokemon once to start a catch attempt**.

There are possible issues you may be encountering, if tapping once does not initiate a catch attempt:

- **Network Issues**: If the game is having problems communicating with the server, it may be unable to confirm your selection. As a result, your taps may not be validated, and will in turn not register as actual input. *This is especially an issue so close to launch*, as the servers are constantly being overloaded.
- **GPS Issues**: Once you start catching a pokemon, location does not appear to make a difference. However, you still need to be within proximity of the pokemon, to initiate the catch attempt. If your GPS is experiencing any issues, it might invalidate your proximity to the pokemon. In turn, your game may *think* you are not close enough to catch the pokemon, and reject your input.
- **Game Bug**: Pokemon Go is still very new, and there are a few game-breaking bugs that have been found, but other users. *Even for a game that has been through considerable beta testing, it is common for bugs to pop up on release, when there are many more users playing*. If you find no other possible cause, it would be a good idea to [submit a Bug Report to Niantic Labs](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222061187-Report-a-bug). There is no guarantee they will deliberately respond to you, but if it confirms to be a bug, your report will help towards a quicker resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to ever tap a Pokemon in the wild once.

The game right now is just extremely laggy and the servers are still (likely) on fire following the launch.